# Mapkit, how to change annotation coordinates to nearest address?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, annotations, mapkit

I have a navigation application I am working on, and one use of it is that it can calculate the average of all the annotations coordinates placed by the user(through a search table, and each annotation is placed when they press a result) and find what you might call a middle point, in between all the annotations.  This midpoint, however, only goes by coordinates at the moment, meaning that depending on where the users current annotations are, this mid point could wind up in the middle of a lake or a forest, which is not helpful.  I want it to find the nearest address to the coordinates of my middle point, and redirect the annotation to there instead.  Here's how the annotation is created:

```
@IBAction func middleFinderButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let totalLatitude = mapView.annotations.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.coordinate.latitude }

    let totalLongitude = mapView.annotations.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.coordinate.longitude }

    let averageLatitude = totalLatitude/Double(mapView.annotations.count)

    let averageLongitude = totalLongitude/Double(mapView.annotations.count)

    let centerPoint = MKPointAnnotation()

    centerPoint.coordinate.latitude = averageLatitude
    centerPoint.coordinate.longitude = averageLongitude

    mapView.addAnnotation(centerPoint)
}
```

How can I get this annotation 'centerPoint' to adjust to the nearest address? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you will need to do a double look up: one to find an existing address based on a location and one to find the coordinates to that address once an address is found. I have not tried this, but it might work:  use `CLGeocoder`:: for the first part use `reverseGeocodeLocation` and for the second part use `geocodeAddressString`. Let us know how it works!

Comment: @Barns Thanks for the help!  I have this so far centerPoint.coordinate.latitude = averageLatitude
        centerPoint.coordinate.longitude = averageLongitude
        
        CLGeocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation()
        CLGeocoder.geocodeAddressString()
        
        mapView.addAnnotation(centerPoint)  I need arguments for each line, what should I put, and this is the order and way I should do it right? here is the github link if you want to try it: https://github.com/derekvandermark/VHNavigationAppOfficial-v-0.74

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use a reverse geocode here returning an MKPlacemark. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder/1423621-reversegeocodelocation) suggests that normally just one placemark will be returned by the completion handler, on the main thread, so you can use the result straightaway to update the UI. MKPlacemark conforms to the annotation protocol so you can put it directly on the map:

```
func resolveAddress(for averageCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, completion: @escaping (MKPlacemark?) -> () ) {

    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    let averageLocation = CLLocation(latitude: averageCoordinate.latitude, longitude: averageCoordinate.longitude)
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(averageLocation) { (placemarks, error) in
        guard error == nil,
            let placemark = placemarks?.first
             else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        completion(MKPlacemark(placemark: placemark))
    }
}

@IBAction func middleFinderButton(_ sender: Any) {

    // your code to find center annotation

    resolveAddress(for: centerPoint.coordinate) { placemark in 
        if let placemark = placemark { 
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(placemark) 
        } else {
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(centerCoordinate) 
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm slightly confused.  Are you suggesting that I should use this inside my middleFinderButton (I know I can't put an extension in there) or completely scrap my button or something else?  I don't 100% understand how the geocoder works, still researching... Thanks :)

Comment: Don't worry about that extension, you don't need it. Kick off the reverse geocode in your button's action method after you come up with a center point. Then add the placemark that comes back to the map as an annotation instead of that calculated point. If nothing comes back or there's an error you can fall back to your calculated center point.

Comment: So the part in the button works fine, but for the actual resolve address function I have the following errors: for the 'else' it says 'closure expression is unused' and suggests I put a 'do' after 'else'.  Then for 'let placemark = placemarks.first,' it says, 'expected expression in conditional', and for 'nearest' on the bottom its saying it's an unresolved identifier, so what should I have resolver = ?Thanks again lol

Comment: Update, I have changed it so that it's 'let placemark = placemarks?.first' ..... now the only issue is again 'nearest' being an unresolved identifier... should I set nearest equal to something and if so what? or is there a built in variable of some sort I should use?  :)))

Comment: UPDATE: I got it to work, just put placemark as the argument for the completion.  Thanks a lot.  I don't 100% understand why this works as I am still learning all this mapkit syntax, but thanks.  I'm gonna edit the answer and check it :)